# how to display different grids with different dataSource dynamically

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I have to display KendoUI splitters dynamically depending upon the records in the database.
If i have n records in my database,I have to display "n-1" splitters.and in each partition I have to display KendoGrid with different dataSource.
I have implemented ajax to get the records from database,In the success function depending upon the length I am able to display required number of splitters. 
In each splitter I put a grid like,

```
        success: function (json) {
            for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
               var div = document.createElement('div');
               var griddatSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                    transport: {
                        read: {
                            url: "/Home/splitter",
                            type: "POST",
                            dataType: "json"
                        }
                    },
                    batch: false,
                    schema: {
                        model: {
                            id: "iD",
                            fields: {
                                iD: { type: "number" },
                                name: { type: "string" },
                                email: { type: "string" }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                });

                $('<div id = ' + json[i].name + '>').appendTo("#splitter");
                $("#" + json[i].name).kendoGrid({
                    dataSource: griddatSource,
                    selectable: "multiple",
                    columns: [{ field: "name", title: "Name" },
                              { field: "email", title: "Email"}],
                    editable: false

                }).data("kendoGrid");
            }


            $("#splitter").kendoSplitter({
                orientation: "horizontal"
            });
          }
```

Now,I am able to display splitters dynamically and in each splitters I am able to load the grid,but I want to know how to use different different dataSources for different grids.

Thanks

Comment: Are you using jQuery? It looks like you are. If so, add the tag.

Comment: Your code is creating a `div`, giving it an `id`, and then throwing it away (you never add the `div` in `divTag` to anything). That seems odd. Also note that `divTag.setAttribute('id', ...);` is just a roundabout way of writing `divTag.id = ...;`, as `id` is a reflected property.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a variable :

```
var div = $('<div/>');
div.appendTo('#splitter');
div.someStuff();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can get a short idea from this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function fnc()
{
    el=document.createElement('div');
    el.style.backgroundColor="red";
    el.innerHTML="aaa";
    document.getElementById("adiv").appendChild(el);
    //document.getElementById("adiv").innerHTML=var1;
}
</script>
<div id="adiv">
qwerty
</div>
<input type="button" value="click me" onclick="fnc();">
```

Comment: actually i don't want to define any div tag outside.I wrote the above code in my Success function of ajax.In the success I am creating the div and I have to use that div tag.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you mean?

```
function (json) {
        for (var i = 0; i < json.length ; i++) {
            //alert(json[i].name);
            var divTag = document.createElement('div');
            divTag.setAttribute('id', json[i].name);
            var newAddedDiv = $('<div>').appendTo("#splitter");
            newAddedDiv.html('fooooo');
       }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the success of ajax function,I have implemented like

```
    success: function (json) {
                            for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
var j = i+1;                                
var div = document.createElement('div');
     $('<div id = ' + json[i].prj '>').appendTo("#splitter");
    ----------------code for loading grid with different datasource--------------                      
    }
     $("#splitter").kendoSplitter({
      orientation: "horizontal"
                            });

     **code for loading grid with different datasource**
    In the datasource read I gave like 
    transport: {
                                            //passing values to the controller to display grid with different dataSource
                                            read: {
                                                url: function (options) {
                                                    return kendo.format("/Project/Display?selectedId=" + j + ""); 
                                                }

                                            }
                                        }
```